# Docker Toolbox Cleanup Disk Space

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox, resource-cleanup

Using Docker Toolbox for Windows with Virtualbox, I have run the following commands to cleanup docker:

**Containers**

`docker rm -v $(docker ps -a -q -f status=exited)`

**Images**

`docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)`

**Volumes**

`docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)`

However, it seems my disk is still being consumed by my built images?  I have also run the following script for cleanup:

```
#!/bin/bash

# remove exited containers:
docker ps --filter status=dead --filter status=exited -aq | xargs -r docker rm -v

# remove unused images:
docker images --no-trunc | grep '<none>' | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs -r docker rmi

# remove unused volumes:
find '/var/lib/docker/volumes/' -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep -vFf <(
  docker ps -aq | xargs docker inspect | jq -r '.[] | .Mounts | .[] | .Name | select(.)'
) | xargs -r rm -fr
```

I received the following error:

```
An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22status%22%3A%7B%22dead%22%3Atrue%2C%22exited%22%3Atrue%7D%7D: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I believe this is due to my use of Docker Toolbox on a non-Linux system.  Therefore my path to unused volumes is off?

In what directory does Docker Toolbox store the images it creates?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try some commands that were added to version 1.13.0:

```
$ docker system prune
$ docker container prune
$ docker image prune
$ docker volume prune
$ docker network prune
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, my dockerclean script is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remove dead containers
docker ps -f status=dead --format '{{ .ID }}' | xargs -r docker rm -v
# Remove dangling volumes
docker volume ls -qf dangling=true | xargs -r docker volume rm
# Remove untagged images
docker images --digests --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}@{{.Digest}}' | sed -rne 's/([^>]):<none>@/\1@/p' | xargs -r docker rmi
# Remove dangling images
docker images -qf dangling=true | xargs -r docker rmi
# Remove temporary files
rm -f /var/lib/docker/tmp/*
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo. Thank you for this. But I'm running Docker Toolbox for Windows using VirtualBox. Do you know what a docker cleanup script would be for Windows?

Comment: Try running the above `docker` commands without the final `rm`.